# How to run 2 loops side by side in python?

Tags: python, loops

I have tried both of these solutions

```
from multiprocessing import Process

    def loop_a():
    
        while 1:
    
            print("a")
    
    def loop_b():
    
        while 1:
    
            print("b")
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
    
        Process(target=loop_a).start()
    
        Process(target=loop_b).start()
```

and the second solution

```
import threading
import time

def infiniteloop1():
    while True:
        print('Loop 1')
        time.sleep(1)

def infiniteloop2():
    while True:
        print('Loop 2')
        time.sleep(1)

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=infiniteloop1)
thread1.start()

thread2 = threading.Thread(target=infiniteloop2)
thread2.start()
```

but both of these dont work whichever loop is above like in the second case infiniteloop1 is above so infiniteloop1 will run then after it ends infiniteloop2 will run and i want BOTH of them to run at the same time what i think that the problem is that both the loops will take input from user in some kind like in the first loop it will take voice input and in the second loop it will see if a mouse button is pressed. so while one loop is taking input the other wont run something like that is happening from what i think
this is the code of my loops
loop 1

```
def screen_display():
    white = (255, 255, 255)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 600))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Assistant")
    screen.fill(white)
    exit_button = pygame.image.load('cross.png').convert_alpha()
    set_height = exit_button.get_height()
    set_width = exit_button.get_width()
    exit_button_rect = exit_button.get_rect(center=(230, 545))
    settings_button = pygame.image.load('settings.png').convert_alpha()
    pygame.transform.scale(settings_button, (set_height, set_width))
    settings_button_rect = settings_button.get_rect(center=(67, 545))
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
            mousepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    if is_over(settings_button_rect, mousepos):
                        print(1)
                    if is_over(exit_button_rect, mousepos):
                        print(2)
```

loop 2

```
while True:

        # Exception handling to handle
        # exceptions at the runtime

        try:

            # use the microphone as source for input.
            global source2
            with sr.Microphone() as source2:

                # wait for a second to let the recognizer
                # adjust the energy threshold based on
                # the surrounding noise level
                settings()
                print("say the command after the beep")
                SpeakText("What do you want me to do?")
                MyText = speech_text()
                turn_text_to_sense(MyText)
                if 'your name' in MyText:
                    print("You can change my name say 'help' for help")

        except sr.RequestError as e:
            SpeakText("Could not request results please check your internet connection; {0}".format(e))

        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            SpeakText("Couldn't understand what you said, say 'help' for info about commands")
```

there is some more code of other functions but i dont think that they are important

Comment: i turned it to this 
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=game_loop() and screen_display())
thread1.start()
still dosent works

Comment: Please try to write in full sentences, and put periods (full stops) in places that make sense.

Comment: ok sir will do that

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use `threading`

```
import threading 

def loop_a():

    while 1:

        print("a")

def loop_b():

    while 1:

        print("b")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threadings = []

    threadings.append(threading.Thread(target = loop_a))
    threadings.append(threading.Thread(target = loop_b))

    for thread_item in threadings:
        thread_item.start()

    for thread_item in threadings:
        thread_item.join()
```

Comment: It is giving me 5 errors

Comment: Sorry, I edited. Please try again.

Comment: The two threads are not daemon so they won't stop after the main thread exits. If you want them to exit when the main thread exits, you need to add the `daemon = True` in `threading.Thread` constructor.

Comment: ok i am trying again but i think nothing will work

Comment: Here, that works. I tried in my local PC

Comment: nah man only one loops works the loop which is above like in this case the loop_a will work nothing else will work

Comment: i think there is no problem in the *code* the problem is in my loops as i tried them with some other loops and it works but when i try them with my loops they wont work cause what i think is that they both cant get user input at the same time so only one of them works and other one dosen't

Comment: Here the two threads are running. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: no sir only one works or is it what it seems to

Comment: i will give you the code and try and run urself mr. i can guarantee you it will never work how can i giv u code?